# Incorrect rendering in Anaconda + Spyder (wrong colours in text)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, anaconda, rendering, spyder

When opening Anaconda (and starting Spyder from it) today, I experienced some (to me) unexplainable, rendering problems (I'm not sure whether this is the correct term). The text is not displayed as it normally is, see example pictures below:

[This is an example for how it looks like in the Anaconda Navigator (GUI)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31FZm.png)

[This is how the Spyder editor looks like in light mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3TPE.png) -> green  dots inside the black text

[This is how the Spyder editor looks like in dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnxLe.png)-> pink  dots inside the black text

The icons in Spyder and the text inside the documentation window are not touched by this.

**The warning that I get in the shell is: `libpng warning: bKGD: invalid`**, but I did not find any helpful resources on it.
`

I do not have these problems in any other program, everything looks normal.

I uninstalled and reinstalled anaoconda completely using this approach ([link to guide](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu-20-04/)), which is basically what the Anaconda Docs are recommending, but the same thing occurs in the fresh install as well.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS with KDE, Anaconda Navigator 1.9.12 and Spyder 4.1.4.

Can you point me in a direction of how to resolve this? Thanks a lot!

Let me know if any useful information is missing!

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it by first install ImageMagick

```
sudo apt install imagemagick-6.q16
```

and then running

```
cd <anaconda location>
mogrify $(find . -name '*.png')
```

This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but that does not solve the problem for  me unfortunately. The text still looks the same.
Do you have any hypothesis why this behaviour occurs?
And howis mogrify supposed to change the PNG files?

Comment: `mogrify $(find . -name '*.png')`  solved `libpng warning: bKGD: invalid`  warning I get. Thanks