# Cannot start the spyder on miniconda on WSL UBUNTU-20.04

Tags: python, spyder, x11, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

I have installed `miniconda` and created a virtual env with the name `dataScience` and installed all the required files for the `spyder` to work on WSL.

I have used the following commands:

1.) Spyder installation:

`conda install matplotlib spyder scipy`

2.) And other dependencies:

`sudo apt-get install libxcursor-dev`

`sudo apt-get install alsa`

`sudo apt install libegl1-mesa libegl1`

3.) And installed the X11 client on Windows 10 by downloading `VcXsrv`

4.) After that added the following scripts in `./bashrc`:

```
DISPLAY=:0
export DISPLAY
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/mnt/d/codes/py38/dataScience"
LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
Export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT
```

5.) And did `source ~/.bashrc` and in WSL ubuntu-20.04 LTS terminal I ran the command `spyder` (after starting the `X server` on windows10) and I got the following error:

**The problem:**

```
[6876:6820:1011/001550.176657:FATAL:dev_linux.cc(29)] Check failed: 0 == ret (0 vs. -22)
#0 0x7f0a83sd60be <unknown>
#1 0x7f0a837y86c2 <unknown>
#2 0x7f0a878j4c18 <unknown>
#3 0x7f0a847ekljb <unknown>
#4 0x7f0a83f8d9e3 <unknown>
#5 0x7f0a83f31090 <unknown>
#6 0x7f0a83f326e8 <unknown>
#7 0x7f0a83f32a7b <unknown>
#8 0x7f0a83f34782 <unknown>
#9 0x7f0a83f30438 <unknown>
#10 0x7f0a83f4kj9b <unknown>
#11 0x7f0a83a470dc <unknown>
#12 0x7f0a83a4lode <unknown>
#13 0x7f0a83f65678 <unknown>
#14 0x7f0a83f6pqab <unknown>
#15 0x7f0a9db66cx9 start_thread
#16 0x7f0a9da82093 clone
[6876:6566:0100/000000.379311:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(41)] Invalid node channel message
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Am new in this field and scratching my head right now.
If anyone has the solution do answer. Thank you!

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) We don't support WSL right now, sorry. My only recommendation (because the error seems hard to fix) is to use a Linux virtual machine instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your problem with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. However, I was able to get Spyder to work with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS following the same instructions.

To get Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, make sure WSL is enabled on your windows machine and then download Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from the Microsoft Store.

On step 4, change Export on the last line to a lower case e.

```
DISPLAY=:0
export DISPLAY
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/mnt/d/codes/py38/dataScience"
LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT
```

For those who are not running within a viritualenv, `export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/mnt/d/codes/py38/dataScience"`line can be omitted.

Secondly, you also need to install the package `sudo apt-get install libxss1` `sudo apt-get install libxtst6` and `sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins`

After that, restart your terminal. Then type `spyder`and everything should work. You may get warnings along the lines of `libpng warning: bKGD: invalid` however, these aren't critical. If you feel the need to fix them, then refer to : [Incorrect rendering in Anaconda + Spyder (wrong colours in text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63302911/incorrect-rendering-in-anaconda-spyder-wrong-colours-in-text)